# How to display 00*** number in console?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 000077;
```

I would like to see in console.log(a) 000077. How is it possible to perform this?

Comment: Have you tried making your variable a string?

Comment: Convert it to a string and then dynamically pad it, e.g. `a.toString(8).padStart(6, '0')`.

Comment: As a note: as long as you do not use es5 or newer in strict mode then the number would be interpreted as octal when you prefix it with `0` see [MDN: Numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates)

Answer (score 0):

You could format the number as string with [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

```js
var a = 77;

console.log(a.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumIntegerDigits: 6, useGrouping: false }));
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
var a = 000077;
```

make it a string

```
var a = "000077";
```

Comment: toString() helps too.

Comment: @Feathercrown Not in this case. `(000077).toString() === "63"`. That's because starting a number with `0` indicates an octal number.

Comment: Oh. Never mind then :3

Comment: Use the toString radix.

Comment: it´s treated as octal, so, won´t work

Comment: hmmmm, that is annoying... why not try `000077.toString(8)`

Comment: Does a=a+"" work?

Comment: @Feathercrown no, as `toString` is the first step in that

Comment: @Feathercrown `000077 === 63`. No matter what method you use to convert that to a string, it's underlying value is still `63`.

Comment: hmm.... that's very annoying.

Comment: That's not annoying, that's how octal notation works. Mathematically speaking numbers cannot have leading 0s